# Problem displaying OpenLayers KML layer in IE

Tags: openlayers-2

I am serving the following files from a the same directory on localhost:

```
map.html
OpenLayers.js
output.kml
```

*map.html* simply creates an OpenLayers map and displays the KML file as per the [OpenLayers example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml-layer.html). I access it via *http://localhost:8080/map.html* and it all works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE. In IE I get the navigation buttons but no map. The [OpenLayers example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml-layer.html) does work in IE...

The contents of *map.html* are shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Map</title>
<script src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%" id="map"></div>
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">      

var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

  <!-- Add background map -->  
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
    map.addLayer(wms);

    <!-- Add kml layer -->  
    var kml = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "output.kml",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: true, 
                extractAttributes: true,
                maxDepth: 2
            })
        })
    });
    map.addLayer(kml);

    <!-- Zoom -->
    kml.events.register("loadend", kml, function (e) {
    map.zoomToExtent(kml.getDataExtent());
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have an error in the javascript code which is only triggered by IE.
To better understand what's going on in IE I recommend you install the Developer Toolbar, available as a free add-on from Microsoft:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359

IE9 should already have it installed by default.

After installing the IE Developer Toolbar open it by pressing F12 and then look for errors in the javascript console.

Alternatively you can comment out portions of code starting from *kml.events.register* and see if that fixes it.

**Updated after comment**

IE chokes because the web server does not return application/xml as the content type. Use the dev toolbar to confirm (inspect network traffic).

To fix configure files with .kml extension as application/xml into your web server configuraion.

Comment: It is the KML Vector layer that breaks IE. It's an unknown Javascript error and from what I have read may be related to IE's same origin policy, even though the KML, HTML and javascript are hosted on the same server.

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your comment

Comment: I added the mime mapping to jetty but still got the same issue: `SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. OpenLayers.js, line 2589 character 96`.

Comment: Could you make the map publicly available so that we can look at at it?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be because of the 'loadend' event? I think it does have issues with IE